# Using two strings on one textView in Android

Tags: java, android, string

I'm working on a project where the user navigates through a series of screens, and on the last screen the data from the previous screens are combined to form a message. As of right now, I have 3 strings (that aren't defined in xml) and I want to merge them. My initial thought was to do something like this:

```
TextView.setText(string1, string2, string3);
```

Although that didn't work. How should I tackle this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the concatenation operator `+`:

```
TextView.setText(string1 + string2 + string3);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to merge the 3 String, then use **only overloaded operator in Java, and that is "+"**

In other words concatenation.

```
String s = string1 + string2 + string3;

TextView.setText(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is just a plain Java problem. In Java, when you want concatenate multi string, you use this syntax :

`String result = StringA + StringB + StringC`

And you use `Android widget to set it :

`textView.setText(stringD)`

So, the answer is :

`textView.setText(StringA + StringB + StringC)`

Hope this help :)